# Create Unique list from dataframes (1-7), Create individual excel files with data from dataframes 1-7 on different sheets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have multiple SQL queries that I have written within Jupyter and saved them as df, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7

I have been able to take the unique names for the individual dataframes:

```
names=df,df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7['A'].unique().tolist()
```

With that I then want to create individual workbooks for each of the individual names found in column A and on separate tabs (which I want to be able to name) have the data with name 1 from df on sheet 1, data with name 1 from df1 on sheet 2, etc.

I currently have this right now, however, it is only able to capture df and  it is not working as expected

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os
path="/name"
os.chdir(path)
for i in names:
    writer = ExcelWriter(str(i)+'.xlsx')
    i=pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['A']==i])
    i.to_excel(writer)
```

Additional info:

[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Yub.png)

[Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96MIF.png)

[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiLVN.png)

Updated with scenario
[Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnQxA.png)
[Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wARiL.png)

So here, 
I have 2 dataframes, each has Name1 and Name2. I want an excel sheet named BOB + SAM, have that dataframes name as the sheet name and the one record that is it. Ryan Connor is in both dataframes, so I want to create an excel file named Ryan + Connor, have dataframe 1 record on sheet 1 (named something) and dataframe 2 record on sheet 2

Comment: It is unclear what you are attempting. Unique names *across* all 7 dfs? Or within each of the 7 dfs? Either way, this number of unique names may be lower or greater than 7. And are all dfs the same shape (rows and columns)?

Comment: each of the 7 dfs could have the same or different names. the counts will be different and the columns are different however all of the columns that I am looking at are all named 'Names'. The count of unique names will definitely be greater than 7

Comment: Can you post a small example of your initial setup and desired Excel data? Thanks.

Comment: @Parfait I have just updated with additional info. The code right now is only taking the one SQL query and dividing by the unique name column and then creating the individual excel sheets with the unique names and the data that pertain to the unique name. in the code above I took the unique names from all 7 queries but now what I am trying to figure out is how to get the data for all 7 queries for each unique name (if they are on individual SQL queries) and put them on separate tabs so unique name of 'Bryan' would have tab 1 with the data from SQL 1, tab 2 with the data from SQL 2, etc.